# Why does Arrow not work well with Scaled coordinates in 3D?

Tags: graphics, bugs, graphics3d

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 10.4 or earlier.**

---

I am a little puzzled by the fact that if I try to use `Arrow` with `Scaled` coordinates in 3 dimensions the arrowheads are all over the place.  Note `Arrow` *should* work with `Scaled` coordinates as it is mentioned in the [relevant documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Arrow.html). So while this:

```
pt2D = (Scaled /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}]);
```

works fine:

```
Graphics@{Arrow@#}& @ pt2D
```

[image]

this:

```
pt3D = (Scaled /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 3}]);
```

gives the arrowhead detached from the arrow:

```
Graphics3D@{Arrow@#}& @ pt3D
```

[image]

and the same thing happens with `Tube`d arrows. Here's one from the middle to the edge of a plot:

```
Show[Plot3D[Sin[x - y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Green], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[Tube[#]]}& @ {Scaled[{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}],Scaled[{1, 1, 1}]}], ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Is this in any way expected behaviour? If not, can anyone recommend an easy fix?

Comment: Ok, I can test it now and can confirm this. I do not see how it my be considered expected behaviour imo.

Comment: I think this is closely related to an issue I addressed on [my web page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#Arrows3D) some time ago. I agree with @Kuba that it's not expected behavior. If you want, I could post the arrow function from my web site as an answer...

Comment: Since we seem to have agreement that this is not the expected behaviour I added the bugs tag.

Comment: @Jens ah, I should have looked on your website before asking. If you can find the time that would be great but it's not a pressing issue - I was just puzzled by this.

Comment: @gpap I just added an answer - my own approach was simply to avoid scaled coordinates as much as possible...

Comment: Was this bug really fixed properly? E.g. the following still looks wrong in 12.3: `Graphics3D[{Arrow@{Scaled[-{0.1, 0.1, 0.1}, {0, 0, 0}], Scaled[{0.1, 0.1, 0.1}, {0, 0, 0}]}}, PlotRange -> 2]` (replace `Arrow` with `Line` to see what it should look like)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug which seems to be related to the fact that the *foreshortening* of the arrow is not scaled correctly with the end points of the arrow. The head and shaft of the arrow are treated separately, which may have some benefits (for example, it allows you to independently specify an option `Appearance` in `Arrowheads` that determines if the head appears projected in 3D or not). However, in this case, the scaling is out of sync. Strangely, this appears to happen only with the default arrow head.

So the simplest workaround (*if you need to use scaled coordinates*) is to define a **custom** arrow head:

```
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[{{.01, 1, 
     Graphics3D[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}]]}}], 
  Arrow[Tube[Scaled /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {.9, .9, .9}}]]}]
```

[image: arrow 3d]

In 2D, the arrow head is a polygon, and you could use the following:

```
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[{{.02, 
     1, {Graphics[
        Polygon[
         {{-1, 1/2}, {1/2, 0}, {-1, -1/2}, {-8/9, 0}, {-1, 1/2}}
        ]], 7/9}}}], 
  Arrow[Scaled /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {.9, .9, .9}}]}]
```

[image: arrow 2D]

Comment: Thanks! The reason I am using scaled coordinates is that it's really easier to annotate a plot with them. I have upvoted and plan to accept this. My only reservation is that if the plot range is a bit uneven weird things happen to the arrow head despite the scaling: `Show[Plot3D[Sin[(x - y)/40], {x, 0, 30 π}, {y, 0, 30 π}], Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[{{.02, 1, {Graphics[Polygon[{{-1, 1/2}, {1/2, 0}, {-1, -1/2}, {-8/9, 0}, {-1, 1/2}}]], 7/9}}}], Arrow[Scaled /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {.9, .9, .9}}]}]]` (this is not to do with your answer, it is happens anyway and is more prevalent with `Tube`)

Comment: @gpap That's a great example, very entertaining... somebody at Wolfram really should re-think the way arrows wok in 3D. This internal use of `Scaled` for the heads causes so much headache.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. This is entertaining until it becomes annoying methinks. In any case thanks a lot for your help