# Arrowhead becomes unattached to line in a Graphics3D Manipulate

Tags: bugs, graphics3d

I'm trying to `Manipulate` a `Graphics3D` figure, and am seeing some errors. If I execute the following code, and move the slider, the head on one of arrows bounces around, unattached to the line of the arrow:

```
Manipulate[
 p = {px, 0.8, 1.2};
 q = {0.4, -1, -0.4};
 a = 1.65 Normalize[q - p];
 Graphics3D[{
   Arrow[{p + a, q}],
   Arrow[{p, p + a}],
   {Opacity[0], Cuboid[p, p + a]}
   }, PlotRange -> 2],
 {px, -2, 2}
 ]
```

If I comment out either the cuboid, or the second arrow, the arrowhead doesn't bounce around. How can I prevent this problem with the arrowhead?

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  There is no syntax in which your second and third equal signs are valid.  Also, do not use upper-case letters for variables as they may conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal function or symbol names.

Comment: I works for me in 10.1. I fixed a syntax error for you, so please run the code and see if the problem is still there for you. Is it the upper or lower arrow?

Comment: I can confirm that the fixed code still exhibits the problem on my system (10.0, Mac), and that using lower-case variables instead of upper-case does not fix the problem.  The lower arrow (which is the first one in the Graphics3D list) is the one whose arrowhead placement bounces around.

Comment: The problem appears on my Mac with v10.1 for the arrowhead for `Arrow[{P + A, Q}]`

Comment: Same here with 10.0.2 for Mac.

Comment: no issue w/ 10.1, linux.

Comment: Re Stork: Yes, I know about upper case. I actually use script variables for my vectors, but on this site it is rendered as \\[ScriptCapitalP], which looks silly. And I have no idea what your complaint about my equal signs means.

Comment: I am using a Mac. Could it be OS specific?

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does Arrow not work well with Scaled coordinates in 3D?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46356/245).  I don't see this issue in version 8, but the work-around in the linked question may be of interest here, too.

Comment: In your original post you wrote `P = {Px, 0.8, 1.2}; = {0.4, -1, -0.4}; = 1.65 Normalize[Q - P];` which is nonsense, I corrected it after David wrote his comment. I'm using OS X and can't see the problem in either 10.0 or 10.1.

Comment: No issue on V10.1, Win7-32.

Comment: Given that I see 3 confirmations I've added the "bugs" tag. It looks like this is OS related and it is therefore clearly a job for support@wolfram.com.

Comment: No problem in 9.0.1 in the Windows front end. Seems Mac-specific.

Comment: @Pickett: Oops sorry. I was hacking this down to bare essentials from a much larger piece of code. Must have screwed up.